# Check whether an object implements specific interface in VB6

Tags: vb6

How can i check whether an object implements specific interface in VB6? I have the following code:

```
Dim nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim element As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

...

For Each node In nodes.childNodes
    If (node is MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement (how to do this?)) Then
        Set element = node
        ...
    Else
        ...
    End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
If (node is MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement (how to do this?)) Then
```

with

```
If TypeOf node Is MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement Then
```

FYI: Before using `TypeOf` you have to be sure `node` is not `Nothing` otherwise it will raise a run-time error *Object variable (or with block) not set*.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, does the function call TypeName(node) return "MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement" for you? If so that might be the solution.

Comment: Actually, TypeName probably returns the static type, not the dynamic type, so this probably won't help.

Comment: Well, according to this article (http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/2949) you can determine the runtime type of a Variant using TypeName() so go ahead and give it a shot. Try it with node as a Variant if it doesn't work with node as a MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode.

Comment: thanks, TypeName worked even without Variant. Although I dislike string comparison. That doesn't feel clean to me. I'll use it as the final solution if nothing cleaner will found.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign it to 'element' and if assignment resumes in error, try next interface.